# Object properties and Variables

Tags: powershell

What I am working with is this (Exchange online powershell):

```
get-publicfolder -Identity "\TestFolder" -Recurse|Where{$_.mailenabled -eq "true"}
```

So what I am interested in is getting the `parentpath` and `name` properties from that.
How do I assign that to a variable so parentpath and name are on the same line
Right now if I do

```
$myvar = $MailEnabledFolder.parentpath,$MailEnabledFolder.name
```

Then the variable is built like:

- \TestFolder
- \TestFolder\Test3
- \TestFolder\Test3
- Info
- Processing
- QA

I want it to be

- \TestFolder\Info
- \TestFolder\Test3\Processing
- \TestFolder\Test3\QA

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$MailEnabledFolder.parentpath` and `$MailEnabledFolder.name` values are apparently *arrays* of values, so you must process them in pairs:

```
$array1 = $MailEnabledFolder.parentpath
$array2 = $MailEnabledFolder.name

foreach ($i in 0..($array1.Count-1)) {
  Join-Path $array1[$i] $array2[$i]
}
```

Comment: Hey mklement0  I tried to find a way to contact you directly, but I am not able to find anyway on here.  Would you be able to explain how the increment in the foreach loop works?  In other things I have used, it is usually along the lines of ++i to increment.  Here in Powershell it seems to be a bit different.  TIA

Comment: @user13124883. `..` is the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-), and `0..($array1.Count-1)` creates an _array of indices_ that the `foreach` then loops over. While somewhat wasteful in terms of memory, it is usually actually faster (and easier to write) than a regular `for` loop, which you could use as well: `for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array1.Count; ++i) { ... }`